# How to get Infiniband RX/Tx info

Tags: linux, infiniband

Is there any tools which gather and show infiniband RX/TX info ?

Answer (score 7):

You can query the Infiniband performance counters to get such info.  With Openfabric's infiniband-diags package, the perfquery tool should be sufficient for your needs.  Here's a quick example:

```
> /usr/sbin/perfquery
# Port counters: Lid 22 port 1 (CapMask: 0x200)
PortSelect:......................1
CounterSelect:...................0x0000
SymbolErrorCounter:..............0
LinkErrorRecoveryCounter:........0
LinkDownedCounter:...............0
PortRcvErrors:...................0
PortRcvRemotePhysicalErrors:.....0
PortRcvSwitchRelayErrors:........0
PortXmitDiscards:................0
PortXmitConstraintErrors:........0
PortRcvConstraintErrors:.........0
CounterSelect2:..................0x00
LocalLinkIntegrityErrors:........0
ExcessiveBufferOverrunErrors:....0
VL15Dropped:.....................0
PortXmitData:....................237939
PortRcvData:.....................128199
PortXmitPkts:....................4165
PortRcvPkts:.....................4164
```

I think the last 4 fields are the data you're interested in.  See the manpage for details on various other options.

Comment: The problem with perfquery is that the counters top out at 4294967295 which depending on your application it doesn't take that long to get there. You can reset it to zero with ibclearcounters but that clears the counters for the entire network. If you are doing IPoIB you could use other system accounting tools (sysstat) to get that info but you would be missing out on your other traffic, which is why I'm here looking for a solution.

Comment: I looked a little deeper at perfquery after the last comment and found that 'perfquery -x' will report 64 bit values so it much more useful than I previously believed.

Comment: There is also ibquerryerrors from the infiniband-diags package that can gather counters from the whole network. Moreover, you can use ibdiagnet which is also a part of OFED.